# deployed app does not reflect local release testing?

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-navigation-drawer in my RN project. I have a left drawer navigation item and I previously changed the name of this item but for some reason the name change wasn't reflected in the subsequent app that was pushed to Google Play.  So I added a TEST button to the left nav drawer as well as to the bottom of another screen.  Then I did a bundleRelease and tested the release bundle locally using:

react-native run-android --variant=release

Both of the new TEST buttons were displayed as expected in my local release test, and the left nav item name displayed in my local release test as expected as well.  But then I uploaded the latest aab to Google play, and the new TEST buttons are included in the latest downloadable version (including the TEST button in the left nav drawer), but the left nav item name is still 2 versions old.  There is no reference in my RN project codebase to the old left nav item name, yet the old left nav item name still displays in the downloadable app instead of the new one.

I did gradlew clean and I'm really not sure what to do at this point.  I'll probably post a thread to react-navigation-drawer Issues on github:  https://github.com/react-navigation/drawer/issues.   I was thinking about contact Google Play support but I'm pretty sure that they simply push out what is given to them.  Have you ever experienced behavior like this?  What would you recommend as next steps at this point?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the previous aab or apk file, and then rebuilding, I had a similar issue where it would not overwrite if an existing file was there.